# DropWizard Authenticator using its own Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate, authentication, dropwizard

I'm using DropWizard and I have an Authenticator that loads a User object that has lazily instantiated collections.  In the Resource I try to access those collections but I get a LazyInitilizationException reporting no session - but I'm in a session because the method is annotated @UnitOfWork.

I can fix this by reloading the user object in the Resource's method, but I thought the Authenticator works in the same hibernate session as the Resource call.  Am I doing it wrong?  Is there a way to avoid having to reload the user?

Here is a hint of my code:

`PasswordAuthenticator`

```
public class PasswordAuthenticator  implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> {

  private UserDAO userDAO;

  public PasswordAuthenticator(UserDAO userDAO) {
    this.userDAO = userDAO;
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = credentials.getUsername();
    User user = userDAO.getUserByUsername(username);
    // check password stuff
    return Optional.of(user);
  }
}
```

`TicketResource`

```
@Path("/tickets/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TicketResource {

  @GET
  @UnitOfWork
  public List<Ticket> getTickets(@Auth User caller) {
    for(Ticket t : caller.getTickets()) {  // Exception thrown here
      // processing each ticket stuff
    }
    return listOfTickets;
  }
```

Comment: Does the constructor have the userDao object available? (Is the constructor used?). If not: Add a bean configuration for `userDao` (`@Autowired` or other preferred style)

Comment: You mean for the TicketResource?  No.  TicketResource does have a constructor (I omitted that from the code to keep it brief), but the resource would not need a userDao (and therefore the constructor doesn't currently take one) if I didn't need to reload the user.